# Outrageous scores values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

please can someone help me out here. I am trying to display highscores and scores on my game over screen using the code below but I get these values

High: *327178665342*

Score: *89254400*

which are not consistent with what the actual scores I have on the hud display.

This is the code I am using to retrieve and display the scores:

```
-(id)init{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {

      int score;
    _score = score;
    self.scoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",_score];

        // 6
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger highScore = [defaults integerForKey:@"BatHighScore"];

        // 7
    if(score >= highScore) {
        highScore = score;
        [defaults setInteger:score forKey:@"BatHighScore"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    self.highScoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High:    %d",highScore]

   }
 return self;
}

@end
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

It is likely that you never initialize `score` in your code and get garbage value.

```
int score;      // garbage
_score = score;
```

Try initializing `score` with default value you should get better results.
It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here, maybe you want to define an designated initializer like that :

```
-(id)initWithScore:(NSInteger)score {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
       _score = score;
       // ...
```

Comment: Good one. I missed that when I looked through it.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for your reply but I have included the "initWithSCore:(NSInteger)score" and as soon as the game Over layer is called, all I get is a black screen.

Comment: @Zaki - no problem ! remember the idea here is that the integer wasn't initialized. I doubt that implementing another initializer simply leads to a black screen, but I'm sure asking the right question about that here is a good idea ;) However, I was correct about the garbage value.